# Unable to combine specific lines in notepad++ files using nested for loops

Tags: python-3.4

I'm trying to compare portions of lines in two notepad++ files against each other using two variables(vg_line and sn_line)in order to combine them together if equal. Once it has found its pair it prints out certain information from each for loop, but it only finds the first pair and doesn't continue to loop through vg_lines file in order to compare other lines with sn_lines file.

```
input_file = open(input_VG_name)
input_Server_name = open(input_Server_name)

for line in input_file:

    line_data = line.strip()
    vg_line = line_data[0:44]
    volume_group = line_data[44:58]

    for line1 in input_Server_name:

        line_data = line1.strip()
        sn_line = line_data[0:44]
        server_name = line_data[46:64]

        if vg_line == sn_line:
            print(vg_line, volume_group, server_name)
```

First post so any tips on what I can do better coding/asking questions is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reading the files

Try the following:

```
input_file = r'c:\file.txt'
input_Server_name = r'c:\server_file.txt'

with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():

        line_data = line.strip()
        vg_line = line_data[0:44]
        volume_group = line_data[44:58]

        with open(input_Server_name, 'r') as file1:
            for line1 in file1.readlines():

                line1_data = line1.strip()
                sn_line = line1_data[0:44]
                server_name = line1_data[46:64]

                if vg_line == sn_line:
                    print(vg_line, volume_group, server_name)
```

The thing is: this code will have to read the second file for every line in the first file (which is what I got from your original code).

There are other methods two match to files up, have a search around, there are plenty of answers. Don't forget to check "Code Review" which has some good examples as well.